# "Not Found" Exception when trying to call UpdateAsync or InsertAsync

Tags: xamarin, azure-mobile-services

I'm creating a pretty basic Azure Mobile App based on the TodoItem example, and i'm running into a weird issue. I can connect to the table controller and call ToEnumerableAsync (GET) without issue, but as soon as I call UpdateAsync or InsertAsync, I get a 404 (Not Found) response. I tried recreating the table controller, disabling authentication etc. to no avail.

Log stream on Azure sees the PATCH  message and returns the 404. Not terribly helpful...

my DTO looks like this:

```
public class Patient : EntityData
{
    public string PersonalHealthNumber{ get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

and my client-side patient looks like this:

```
public class Patient
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string PersonalHeathNumber { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    [Version]
    public string Version { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What does your controller look like?

Answer (score 0):

Try derive your client model from that [TableData](https://github.com/adrianhall/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/blob/master/Chapter3/TaskList/TaskList/Abstractions/TableData.cs) base class and remove the 2 properties `Id` and `Version` from your client model because they are in the base class